# Can multiple images be uploaded from one selection field in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, slider, django-imagekit, django-multiselectfield

Can multiple images be uploaded from one selection field for slides in Django? I will use these images in a slide, my slides have over 50. I use manyToManyField but i couldn't do it.

I will take your suggestions into consideration, folks.

Comment: I think you would have to explain a bit more to make your question understandable.

Comment: I need to use 70 images in one slide on my website built with Django, but it takes a lot of time to upload these 70 images separately, so I want to upload them at once from the panel.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about your question due to some missing details. However, you can create an endpoint for saving images. For instance, this endpoint would receive the image along with the ID of the table you want to associate them with.

You can send an infinite number of requests to this endpoint and store a large number of images through it without limitations on the number of images in the form. For example:

```py
# views.py

from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from .models import YourModel

@csrf_exempt  # Use csrf_exempt for demonstration purposes. Make sure to handle CSRF properly in production.
def save_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.FILES.get('image')  # Assuming you're sending the image in a 'POST' request.
        table_id = request.POST.get('table_id')  # Assuming you're sending the table ID along with the image.

        # YourModel is the model associated with the table.
        # You can customize this based on your actual model structure.
        YourModel.objects.create(image=image, table_id=table_id)

        return JsonResponse({'message': 'Image saved successfully.'})
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request method.'})
```

Comment: I need to use 70 images in one slide on my website built with Django, but it takes a lot of time to upload these 70 images separately, so I want to upload them at once from the panel.